# CTCI Ch.1.2 Check Permutation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, permutation, computer-science

Greetings and happy holidays,

My question involves problem "1.2 Check Permutation" from "Cracking The Coding Interview" 6th Ed.

When we compare the two strings, we check for any values in the array that are less than 0. This would indicate different char counts of our two strings. However, shouldn't the comparison be !== 0 instead of < 0? This would catch both over and undercounts of the chars. I didn't see this in the books Errata nor on any related search results.

Below is the provided code solution. (I mainly work in JS, so perhaps I'm reading the code incorrectly)

Many thanks in advance.

```
boolean permutation(String s, String t) {
    if (s.length() != t.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    int[] letters = new int[128]; 

    char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
    for (char c : s_array) {
            letters[c]++;
    }

    
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
        int c = (int) t.charAt(i); 
        letters[c]--;
        if (letters[c] < 0) { // this is the line in question
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison for `!= 0` only makes sense *after* all the differences are computed. The way the code is structured allows an early detection.

The very first test is for `s.length() != t.length()`. Once the code passed it, we know that there are equal number of characters. It means that - if the strings are not permutations - there is a character which appears more in `t` than in `s`. As soon as such character is found, we conclude that `t` is not a permutation.

Comment: Thanks, but would the early check only work if we removed too many chars at some point? I don't see how it would cover the case if the string lengths were equal, but one contained more chars of a certain type than the other string. In that case, we would have to check if the sum is greater than 0 as well. Am I missing something? In other words, the provided solution checks to see if we subtracted too many chars, but what if we didn't subtract enough?

Comment: I understand it now. In the case we remove one of the char too many times, the frequency will go into the negatives and break. But if we didn't remove enough a particular char that should mean that either a non-common char in t was introduced which won't be in the map and we can break from that, or as you stated would introduce a common char that appears too often in t and still lead to a negative result. Thanks again.